# IR LED attachments on the RPi NoIR v2

Tags: camera, led, pi-zero-w

So I bought parts I didn't know would not fit together. Namely, the [Pi NoIR v2 Camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-noir-camera-v2/),
and [IR LED module(s)](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01M134YAX/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

I figured those two combined would be somewhat like the other 5mp IR Cameras on Amazon. It turns out the screw holes don't align properly AND the NoIR does not have metal around the screw holes to even power the IR Leds. No wonder there weren't any articles about it.

The LEDs have what appear to be a light detector which will toggle the device on/off depending on light available in the surrounding, so I assume it will only need power.

I plan on 3d printing an enclosure and connecting those two LEDs to the 5v out of the Pi in parallel. But I need help since I don't really have a background in electrical eng. and too afraid that it might burn down the house.

So my questions are:

1. Since the Pi Zero W runs up to 240mA @ 5v. That means it draws 1.2W
   plus 2x3W LEDs, with a total of 7.2W. I know circuitry isn't as easy
   as it seems, but will a 2A 5v (10W?) Pi charger do the trick?
2. Do I need any resistors or any other electrical components in my setup, just 
   to be on the safe side?
3. Should I run the LEDs straight from the power source, instead of the GPIO pins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No
3. All the Pi GPIO are 3V3 and only supply about 20mA each at most.  So no you can't use the GPIO.  However you can use the 5V and ground pins to power the LEDs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So overall, the setup I had in mind will work?